# laravel mass assignment does not use bindings

Tags: sql, laravel

I just realized that:

```
Model::create(['prop' => 'value']);
```

produces

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(value)
```

While

```
$m = new Model();
$m->value = 'value'
$m->save()
```

results in

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(?)
```

with bindings.

Is this the expected behavior? I thought both would (and should) use bindings